# how to add class in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i need to add class for specific booked and blocked days in fullcalendar, i need to highlight the booked and blocked days with different color. Try tried out with some code but not coming correctly

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'prev,next'
    },
    selectable: true,
    events:[
        {
            title: 'Booked',
            start: '2017-03-11',
            end: '2017-03-22'
        },
        {
            title: 'Block',
            start: '2017-03-28',
            end: '2017-04-6'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: use eventSource instead of events https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

Comment: i tried this also, if i add class it will be very easy for me i can handle this through CSS

Comment: try to use background-event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `eventRender` function in your fullCalendar options:

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if (event.title == "Booked") {
      eventElement.css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  },
```

or add a class with jquery `addClass`

```
eventElement.addClass('yourClass');
```

you can also reference sub-elements if you need

```
eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
    if (event.title == "Booked") {
      eventElement.find("a.fc-content").css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  },
```